# Javascript recursive function to call loop

Tags: javascript, function, loops

In my js program I have a loop that must continue checking if variable x is true. If it isn't, I want it to wait 2 seconds before checking again. I am tackling the problem through recursive functions, yet I do not know if this method is efficient. This is my code, please let me know if this method is good or if there is a better way to do what I am trying to achieve. Thanks.

```
function sleep (time) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
  }

  function loop() {
      if(x == true) {

      } else {
        sleep(2000).then(() => {
            loop();
        });
      }
  }

  loop();
```

Comment: Sure, its fine. As long as you understand the timing here is not precise.

Comment: I would use `setInterval` if you want to loop a timeout.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it more efficiently with `setTimeout(function, ms)`. Here's an example:

```js
x = false;
function loop() {
        if (x == true) {
        
        } else {
           setTimeout(loop, 2000);
           console.log("looped");
        }
}
loop();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do like:

```js
function Looper(loopFunc){
  let interval; 
  this.passed = 0;
  this.loop = milliseconds=>{
    this.passed = 0;
    interval = setInterval(()=>{
      this.passed += milliseconds; loopFunc.call(this);
    }, milliseconds);
    return this;
  }
  this.stop = (milliseconds = 0)=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{
      clearInterval(interval); interval = undefined; 
    }, milliseconds);
    return this;
  }
}
const looper = new Looper(function(){
  console.log('milliseconds passed: '+this.passed);
});
looper.loop(500).stop(5250); // notice it's not exact
```